# class XORShiftRandom in package random cannot be accessed in package org.apache.spark.util.random

Tags: apache-spark

I am trying to use XORShiftRandom from Spark to generate random numbers. The code is very simple:

```
  1 import org.apache.spark._
  2 import org.apache.spark.util.random.XORShiftRandom
  3 
  4 object randomTest {
  5   def main(args: Array[String]) = {
  6     val x = new XORShiftRandom()
  7   }
  8 }
```

The build.sbt is as following:

```
  1 name := "randomTest"
  2 version := "0.01"
  3 scalaVersion := "2.10.4"
  4 libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  5   "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.5.0" withSources() withJavadoc(),
  6   "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-mllib" % "1.5.0" withSources() withJavadoc()
  7   )
```

But I got the error message as shown in the title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The class is marked private to spark package, so you cannot call the constructor. Perhaps you can access some public methods [documented here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.util.random.package) instead.

[Offending line in source code](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/util/random/XORShiftRandom.scala#L38)

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I can put my class inside org.apache.spark just for this random generator to work as an ugly fix. I am wondering if there is any other way to use XORShiftRandom?